# Issue with Spaces when Scripting Scala with Process

Tags: string, scala, scripting, process, system

I am attempting to write an automated script to pngcrush my images (for a website I am working on) and I used scala as a scripting language to write the script to do this. Everything is going well, except that I am having a problem regarding using spaces when I execute the command. I read that you need to use

```
Seq(a,b,c,d)
```

where a,b,c,d are strings (that are meant to be separated by a single space) to deal with how Scala/Java handle Strings

The relevant code I have for generating the command to be executed is here. The result variable contains literal path to every filename

```
for (fileName <- result) {
    val string = Seq("pngcrush","brute","-d","\"" + folder.getPath + "/\"","-e",fileName.getName) ++ fileName.getCanonicalPath.replace(" ","\\ ").split(" ").toSeq
```

I then use

```
string!
```

To execute the command. The problem is that the filename for the last section of the command (after the "-e " flag) isn't executed properly because it cannot deal with the directories that have spaces. An example output is shown below

```
List(pngcrush, brute, -d, "/tmp/d75f7d89-9ed5-4ff9-9181-41ae2fd82da8/", -e, users_off.png, /Users/mdedetrich/3dot/blublocks/src/main/webapp/img/sidebar/my\, group/users_off.png)
```

And if I run reduceLeft to get the spaces back I obviously get what the proper string is.

```
pngcrush brute -d "/tmp/1eaca157-0e14-430c-b0a4-677491d70583/" -e users_off.png /Users/mdedetrich/3dot/blublocks/src/main/webapp/img/sidebar/my\ group/users_off.png
```

Which is what the correct command should be (running the string manually in terminal works fine). However when I attempt to run this through Scala script, I get this

```
Could not find file: users_off.png
Could not find file: /Users/mdedetrich/3dot/blublocks/src/main/webapp/img/sidebar/my\
Could not find file: group/users_off.png
   CPU time decoding 0.000, encoding 0.000, other 0.000, total 0.000 seconds
```

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly? It seems to be a problem with Scala not parsing strings that have spaces (and splitting it with Seq is not working either). I have tried both using a literal string with spaces and Seq, neither of which seem to work.

Comment: I had a similarly-sounding problem recently, where ``cmdSeq!`` didn't work, but ``cmdSeq.mkString(" ")!`` did. Never really figured out where the actual problem was, tough. Anyway, give it a try.

Comment: Nope, still getting the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing this:

```
replace(" ","\\ ").split(" ")
```

*That* is what's splitting the argument, not `Process`. Why don't you just use the following?

```
val string = Seq("pngcrush",
                 "brute",
                 "-d","\"" + folder.getPath + "/\"",
                 "-e",fileName.getName, 
                 fileName.getCanonicalPath)
```

Comment: Oh wow, that actually worked. The reason I was doing
 
 replace(" ","\\ ").split(" ")
 
Was for path names that have spaces in it (i.e. to access a path like /my group/..... in shell you go /my\ group). I am probably too used to shell scripting where you have to literally produce the exact string that you would execute in shell